# Single word to define a person who thinks that there is always a scope for improvement

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a word that defines a person who thinks that there is always a scope for improvement.
Just like the term "perfectionist" that defines a person who always looks for perfection. Is there a term to define who always looks for improvement?

Comment: Perhaps a *tinkerer*.  You don't mention whether this word should have positive or negative connotations.

Comment: A _perfectabilitarian_ is such a person. A _perfectionist_ may be a perfectabilitarian or not, depending on the source for their motivations.

Comment: I've never heard the word *perfectabilitarian* but I quite like it :-). Here is [an example of usage](https://books.google.rs/books?id=wKRvrp-YWVsC&pg=PA131&lpg=PA131&dq=perfectabilitarian&source=bl&ots=wuZL_HJr5V&sig=VnKby1PFTT-MD4etbH_BPiZUoQI&hl=en&sa=X&ei=6_ZmVcrqL8H6sAHH84GABg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=perfectabilitarian&f=false) if you need one.

Comment: Idealist or utopian

Comment: I would call the person an *optimist*.

Answer (score 1):

Meliorism - the belief that the world can be made better by human effort. An intermediate outlook between optimism and pessimism.

Optimism - a tendency to look on the more favorable side or to expect the most favorable outcome of events or conditions.

Dictionary.com

Answer (score 1):

**Overoptimistic** [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/overoptimistic):

> 1. excessively optimistic

Once you're down to the ideal case, that's the best there'll ever be.

**Panglossian** describes someone at the the endpoint of this overoptimistic worldview. [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/panglossian):

> marked by the view that all is for the best in this best of possible worlds :  excessively optimistic

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're knocking `perfectionist`. A perfectionist is always looking for thing to be perfect. The way to make things perfect is to improve them. I'd say that thinking "there is **always** a scope for improvement" is the same as looking for perfection.

Anyway, if you're looking for an alternative (with negative connotations), such a man could be referred to as [Mr. Glass Half-Empty](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=%22mr%20glass%20half%20empty%22&tbm=bks). It is also used to mean a pessimist, though.

Comment: Do you think that perfectionists can sometimes reject efforts at improvement: turn their back on their work because they know it will never be perfect, or crush others' ideas for the same reason?

Comment: I think a perfectionist wants things to be perfect already. Although since things usually aren't, I guess he'd also think that they have room for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

*Perfectionist*, to me, has the connotation that the person's desire for perfection is focused on their own work, perhaps even that it is limited to their own work. You wouldn't call someone a perfectionist because they could see room for improvement in their country's economy and their family's social dynamics and the state of the movie industry and their children's school and ...

What you would call such a person is an *idealist*, a person who thinks everything can be done better and is unsatisfied with the way things are now, who isn't content with pragmatic compromises.

Answer (score 0):

How about "augmentative". I like the play it has, both in sound and in meaning, with "argumentative."

Comment: It already has accepted senses. But not 'of the opinion that there is always room for improvement'.

Answer (score -1):

As per the suggestion of the post the following words  may have a chance. The words are arranged according to my preference:-
♦ exacting
♦ captious
♦fastidious
♦hyper critical
♦ nitpicky♦exceptive

"Carper " may as well have a chance in the light of  John  Bunyan's quotation :
"Come, let my carper to his life now look,/ And find there darker lines than in my book."

Answer (score -1):

Sisyphean?

I know it describes an endless task, but uncertain whether it can be applied to a mentality. None of the terms are complimentary, and most are insulting.

In Psychology 'Constant Improvers' are one of the Myers Briggs Personality Types. (I love Myers Briggs) Have a read of it before you unleash your word on your overly fastidious friend  :)